# ERROR in Plugin "react" was conflicted between "package.json » eslint-config-react-app

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, eslint, oraclelinux

I created a .NET Core React project on Oracle Linux 7. After installing all the necessary dependencies I ran into the following error in the console when I access the app from the web.

*ERROR in Plugin "react" was conflicted between "package.json » eslint-config-react-app » /home/opc/amnathrig/node_modules/eslint-config-react-app/base.js" and "BaseConfig » /usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/eslint-config-react-app/base.js".*

The error message is clear but I have no idea how to get around it.

Comment: I tried renaming eslint-config-react-app in each location by appending -temp but that resulted in other errors popping up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was installing packages to the main application directory instead of the ClientApp folder. I thought about deleting the question but in the event someone else runs into this problem, this may be the cause.

Answer (score -1):

please use `npm update -g` where `g` is global.